# Trying to get HTTP code. Can someone try this code for me in their Python interpretor and see why it doesn't work?

Tags: python, http, exception, url

```
import httplib
def httpCode(theurl):
    if theurl.startswith("http://"): theurl = theurl[7:]
    head = theurl[:theurl.find('/')]
    tail = theurl[theurl.find('/'):]
    response_code = 0
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(head)
    conn.request("HEAD",tail)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    response_code = int(res.status)
    return response_code
```

Basically, this function will take a URL and return its HTTP code (200, 404, etc)
The error I got was:

```
Exception Value:  (-2, 'Name or service not known')
```

I must do it with this method. That is, I am usually passing in large video files. I need to get the "header" and get the HTTP code.  I **cannot** download the file and then get the HTTP code, because it would take too long.

```
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:58:18)
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib
>>> def httpCode(theurl):
...     if theurl.startswith("http://"): theurl = theurl[7:]
...     head = theurl[:theurl.find('/')]
...     tail = theurl[theurl.find('/'):]
...     response_code = 0
...     conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(head)
...     conn.request("HEAD",tail)
...     res = conn.getresponse()
...     response_code = int(res.status)
...     print response_code
...
>>> httpCode('http://youtube.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in httpCode
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 874, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 911, in _send_request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 868, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 740, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 699, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 683, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 498, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>>>
```

Comment: You should post the traceback, not just the error message.

Comment: It works for `http://youtube.com/` (I get a 301).

Comment: Your python code works as expected for me.  Perhaps a failure of your nameservers?  Try looking in your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: What are the values in head and tail? Are you certain that they are being parsed out correctly?

Comment: What do you mean a failure of nameservers?

Comment: Try using the socket module.  Run socket.gethostbyname("domain.you.are.trying.to.hit") and see if it resolved the correct IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked for me, and for one other person who commented.  This implies that the URL you're using is causing a problem with your parsing somehow.  `head` and `tail` should both be examined in order to determine what it thinks the host is.  For example:

```
head = theurl[:theurl.find('/')]
print head
tail = theurl[theurl.find('/'):]
print tail
```

Once you can see what `head` and `tail` are, you can determine if it really should be able to resolve `head`.  For example, what if the url was:

```
http://myhost.com:8080/blah/blah
```

It would fail because of the port number.

Comment: Or if you left off a trailing slash, like http://google.com since find would return -1.  Head would be google.co and tail would be m.

Comment: There's your problem, you need a trailing slash.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comment by Adam Crossland, you should be checking your head and tail values.  In your case, without a trailing slash you end up with

```
head = "youtube.co"
tail = "m"
```

string.find returns -1 if it is not found, hence you are grabbing all but last character for head and only the last character for tail.

Comment: Alex, you should strongly consider using urlparse. It is going to do a better job of dealing with URLs: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html